# How to display RTF text in to tinyMCE editor

Tags: c#, xml, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE editor. I have rtf formatted string in database column which I want to show in the browser editor i.e. tinyMCE. So that, user will edit the text as he wants. But for that I found I need to convert the rtf string in to xml to see it, since my tinyMCE is showing xmls properly. I am able to show the text from rtf string but I misses out the formatting like bold text, red colored text, \n etc. I want to retain all this formatting. How shall I retain the formatting or how shall I display the rtf text with the formatting or how shall I convert rtf text in to xml properly? I want to display rtf text like I am saving it in some rtf file and opening that file in ms word or open office word that way I want  to see the format. rtf is Rich Text format.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your RTF to HTML and use that for TinyMCE, here is a code project article that will get you started :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter